# When logging integer data from bash to a file, what kind of file should be used?

Tags: bash, logging, binary, ascii, gnuplot

I have a Cronjob on my MacOS that stores several user data to files for plotting these. The date is for example CPU usage, RAM, temperature sensors, brightness, battery, in- and outbytes, fanspeed, free disk space and so on.

The data is meant for plotting the results over a long timespan, up to a hole year. The bash-file stores new data every two seconds as long my MacBook is aktive (display awake).

This is an example of the log files:

```
4315681 46 0
4315683 42 0
4315685 40 0
4315687 43 0
```

So, all Characters stored in the files are integers, no floating numbers and no other chars except numbers.

Is it advisable to store these lines in a normal .txt file? Or should I think of other solutions like .xml or .dat extensions. Can I store these numbers in a binary file and would it make sense?

The data will be plotted with Gnuplot. An x-axis for the ID (first column, time format) and the y-axis will be the data from the second column from 0-100.

These questions never affected me, so I haven't any idea about these things, but I wanted to know a bit more about it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `gnuplot` loves text, so leave it text. You might get more mileage out of CSV, though. For example: `4315681,46,0`.